# what is the quotient when $(x^{-1} -1)$ is divided by $(x -1)$ .

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have step by step answer to this question, but I don't get one of the step

\begin{align*}
  &\frac{x^{-1} - 1}{x-1} \\
  &= \frac{\frac{1}{x}-1}{x-1} \\
  &= \frac{1-x}{x} \cdot \frac{1}{x-1} \quad \textrm{I don't understand this step.}\\
  &= \frac{-1}{x}
\end{align*}

Comment: Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Multiply top and bottom by $\frac{x}{x}$

Comment: $$\frac{\frac{1}{x}-1}{x-1} = \frac{\frac{1}{x}-1}{1}\cdot\frac{1}{x-1} = \frac{\frac{1}{x}-\frac{x}{x}}{1}\cdot\frac{1}{x-1} = \frac{1-x}{x}\cdot\frac{1}{x-1}.$$

Answer (score 1):

It could be
$$\frac{\frac{1}{x}-1}{x-1}=\frac{\frac{1-x}{x}}{x-1}\cdot\frac{\frac{1}{x-1}}{\frac{1}{x-1}}=\frac{\frac{1-x}{x}\cdot\frac{1}{x-1}}{1}=\frac{1-x}{x}\cdot\frac{1}{x-1}=\frac{-(x-1)}{x}\cdot\frac{1}{x-1} = \frac{-1}{x}$$
for completeness, assuming $x \neq 1$.